# How to view perl script

Tags: forms, perl, web, action

I have a `form` in html page, which has a perl script in `action=` field. I can see this by doing `view source` in the webpage in web browser.

```
<form action="loginscript.pl" method="post">
```

I want to see what the script is doing, but I dont know how to  view the content of `loginscript.pl`. When I put the perl script in `url` (like `http://web.adress/loginscript.pl`) the script gets executed.

However I dont want to execute the script, I just want to see the script. How to view the script ?

Comment: You can find the script in your server root directory. If you have access to that go and check it.

Comment: No I dont have access to the server. I want to see the perl script from the client web browser.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible, otherwise it will become an security issue.

Answer (score 4):

If the Web server is configured properly you **can't** get source of this CGI script. You can view a source only if you have access to the hosting.